# Creating a jqueryUI sortable list with knockout

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have a UL list that I allow users to move items around. I am binding with knockout as I am wanting to save their selection back into a database.

Sorting works however the UI duplicates the dragged element within the UI. The viewmodel's data is correct and I can see it's not creating an extra element within the data.

I have a a small jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/spnz/JVhZe/)

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JVhZe/2/

I have replaced `ui.item.removeData('previous_index');` with `ui.item.remove()`. `removeData` is a jQuery specific method for cleaning up custom data. You do not have to call this method as Knockout already does this for you when you are unbinding/removing elements.

Btw, I suggest you take a look at this excellent implementation of a Knockout sortable list:

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QWgRF/

Comment: Just wanted to add that the current version of the binding from that fiddle lives here: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

Answer (score 1):

maybe?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
                var curr;
                $("#giftListEditor").sortable({
                    start: function (event, ui) {
                        curr = viewModel.gifts()[ui.item.index()];
                    },
                    update: function (event, ui) {
                        var currIndex = ui.item.index();
                        viewModel.gifts.remove(curr);
                        viewModel.gifts.splice(currIndex == -1 ? 0 : currIndex, 0, curr);
                    }
                }).disableSelection(); 
});
</script>
```